# Excel Nested IF Statement syntax

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to work out how to structure the `IF` statements in Excel. From what Ive read the following should work `=IF((G2=True("MED"),IF(H2=True("HIGH"),IF(I2=True("CRITICAL"), "LOW")` However Im getting errors.

Im Trying to determine if A Row contains a True, in either of those CELLS if it does then display the true value (MEDIUM,HIGH,CRITICAL).

Can anyone point out where im going wrong?

**G2**

```
=IF(E2<=6.9, "MED", "Not MED")
```

**H2**

```
=IF(E2>=7, "HIGH", "Not HIGH")
```

**I2**

```
=IF(E2=10, "CRITICAL", "Not CRITICAL")
```

**Target Cell D2**

```
=IF(G2,"MED",IF(H2,"HIGH",IF(I2,"CRITICAL","LOW")))
```

Comment: it's not clear what are you going to achieve with this `G2=True("MED")`

Comment: should it be: `=IF(G2,"MED",IF(H2,"HIGH",IF(I2,"CRITICAL","LOW")))`?

Comment: All Im trying to achieve is does G2 OR H2 OR I2 have true? If it does show its Value in Target Cell.

Comment: `show its Value in Target Cell` - but if `G2` is `True` how it could also contains `"MED"`?

Comment: @simoco that produces an error in the Value

Comment: what error it's produces?

Comment: can you post a screen of your data?

Comment: Added more details to the POST

Comment: try `=IF(G2="MED",G2,IF(H2="HIGH",H2,IF(I2="CRITICAL",I2,"LOW")))`

Comment: @simoco Rofl I had it very wrong. Thanks, makes sense. Post your Answer ill accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this one works

```
=IF(G2="MED",G2,IF(H2="HIGH",H2,IF(I2="CRITICAL",I2,"LOW")))
```